# a condition for a tightness of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

$f: X\to \mathbb R$ be nontrivial continuous, given the fact that

$\sup \int\limits_df\mu_n<\infty\forall n$, then could anyone tell me whether $\{\mu_n\}$ is a tight sequence of a probability measure on $X$?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f=0$ then the hypothesis says nothing and $(\mu_n)$ need not be tight.

Comment: You are thinking in the wrong direction. If the hypothesis holds for a 'large' funtion you have hopes of proving tightness, but Lipschitz condition makes it 'small'.

Comment: If you assume that $g$ is non-negative and $g(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$ then  $\mu_n$ is tight. Forget about continuity, Lipischitz condition etc. They are not useful.

Comment: The condition is: for every $T \in (0,\infty)$ there exists a  compact set $K$ such that $g(x) >T$ for all $x \notin K$. The function $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous, Lipschitz and satisfies this hypothesis but the only property that is useful is he fact that it tends to $\infty$. You cannot define $\int g d\mu_n$ for $g: X \to X$. You should change the range to $\mathbb R$ so that your question becomes meaningful.